# Mostrar datos de todos los n empleados ingresados, porque solo me muestra datos del ultimo empleado

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles

Programa de listas. Quiero que muestre los datos de todos los n enpleados, porque solo me muestra los datos del ultimo empleado que ingrese. ¿Cómo lo soluciono? Supongo que es con un ciclo, pero no sé donde ingresarlo.

```
print("\n****************CALCULO DE NOMINAS*******************")
n = int(input("\nIngrese la cantidad de empleados a los que desea calcular su sueldo: \n"))
empleados=[]
empleado=[]
if n>0:

   sueldo=0
   ID= 0
   for i in range(n):
       ID = int(input("Ingrese ID del empleado: "))
       sueldo = float(input("Ingrese su sueldo: "))

       if (sueldo>0 and sueldo<=5000):
        retencion=sueldo*0.1
        print("\n****RETENCION DEL 10%****")

       elif (sueldo>5000 and sueldo<=10000):
        retencion= sueldo*0.13
        print("\n****RETENCION DEL 13%****")

       elif (sueldo>10000 and sueldo<=14500):
        retencion= sueldo*0.16
        print("\n****RETENCION DEL 16%****")

       elif (sueldo>14500 and sueldo<=21700):
        retencion= sueldo*0.23
        print("\n****RETENCION DEL 23%****")

       elif (sueldo>21700):
        retencion = sueldo*0.30
        print("\n****RETENCION DEL 30%****")

   pago= sueldo-retencion
   empleado=[ID, sueldo, retencion, pago]
   empleados.append(empleado)
a=0
while a < len(empleados):
   print("EL ID del empleado es \"{}\" ".format(empleado[0]))
   print("El sueldo inicial es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[1]))
   print("La retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[2]))
   print("EL monto a pagar con retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[3]))
   a+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el ultimo `while` no estas indexando nada con el indice a que recorre la lista `empleados`.
Si no que estas indexando la variable `empleado` que se queda con el ultimo valor que colocaste.

Es decir la solución es:

```
a=0
while a < len(empleados):
    empleado = empleados[a]
    print("EL ID del empleado es \"{}\" ".format(empleado[0]))
    print("El sueldo inicial es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[1]))
    print("La retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[2]))
    print("EL monto a pagar con retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[3]))
    a+=1
```

PD: Me tomo la libertad de recomendarte una forma mas *Pythonic* de recorrer la lista de empleados, se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
for empleado in empleados:
    print("EL ID del empleado es \"{}\" ".format(empleado[0]))
    print("El sueldo inicial es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[1]))
    print("La retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[2]))
    print("EL monto a pagar con retención es de ${0:.2f} MXN ".format(empleado[3]))
```

Es mejor por que no tienes que manejar indices y es más compacto.

Comment: El ciclo for fue muy útil, el problema es que si ingreso 2 empleados, solo me sigue los datos de el último empleado que ingresé.
EJEMPLO: 
Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a los que desea calcular su sueldo: 
2
Ingrese ID del empleado: 1
Ingrese su sueldo: 2000

****RETENCION DEL 10%****
Ingrese ID del empleado: 2
Ingrese su sueldo: 6000

****RETENCION DEL 13%****
EL ID del empleado es "2" 
El sueldo inicial es de $6000.00 MXN 
La retención es de $780.00 MXN 
EL monto a pagar con retención es de $5220.00 MXN

Answer (score 1):

ya vi tu problema, las ultimas lineas del for, donde se insertaba el empleado a empleados. Realmente no están dentro del for. Es importante cuidar la sangría de las lineas. Tambien en el ultimo bucle while, cuando insertas en la funcion format empleado[0] realmente estas haciendo referencia siempre al mismo valor, deberia ser i[0] (o cualquier otro nombre de la variable del for) ya que estas recorriendo empleados con el for, pero este arreglo contiene arreglos dentro, entonces con el subindice accedemos a los valores internos de i.

```
print("\n****************CALCULO DE NOMINAS*******************")
n = int(input("\nIngrese la cantidad de empleados a los que desea calcular su sueldo: \n"))
empleados=[]
empleado=[]
if n > 0:
    sueldo=0
    ID=0
    for i in range(n):
        ID = int(input("Ingrese ID del empleado: "))
        sueldo = float(input("Ingrese su sueldo: "))

        if (sueldo>0 and sueldo<=5000):
            retencion=sueldo*0.1
            print("****RETENCION DEL 10%****\n")

        elif (sueldo>5000 and sueldo<=10000):
            retencion= sueldo*0.13
            print("****RETENCION DEL 13%****\n")

        elif (sueldo>10000 and sueldo<=14500):
            retencion= sueldo*0.16
            print("****RETENCION DEL 16%****\n")

        elif (sueldo>14500 and sueldo<=21700):
            retencion= sueldo*0.23
            print("****RETENCION DEL 23%****\n")

        elif (sueldo>21700):
            retencion = sueldo*0.30
            print("****RETENCION DEL 30%****\n")

        pago = sueldo-retencion
        empleado=[ID, sueldo, retencion, pago]
        empleados.append(empleado)

for i in empleados:
    print(f'EL ID del empleado es "{i[0]}"')
    print(f"El sueldo inicial es de {i[1]} MXN ")
    print(f"La retención es de {i[2]} MXN")
    print(f"EL monto a pagar con retención es de {i[3]} MXN")
```